# Package-lock.json does not lock with caret in package.json. (I promise this is not a dupe.)

Tags: npm, package-lock.json

Please don't mark this as a dupe. I've done a lot of research on this and I'm very confused about something specific here.

I keep seeing everywhere (on stackoverflow and in lots of articles) that if you use a caret (^) in your package.json file, package-lock.json will keep whatever specific version you pulled down on your last `npm install`.

But I did this...

- Deleted my node_modules/bootstrap folder.
- Deleted the package-lock.json file.
- Changed the bootstrap line in my package.json file to `^5.0.0`.
- Ran `npm install`.

And it recreated the package-lock.json file with `"bootstrap": "^5.0.0"`.
With that in mind, I looked at the package.json file in node_modules/bootstrap and the version there is `"5.3.0"`.

I understand there are other uses for the package-lock.json like viewing the dependency tree and having the current version's hash but I want to know why everyone says the package-lock.json file is supposed to lock within a version range and why I'm not seeing that here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ok I see now: At the top of the package-lock file, under packages > dependencies, the original caret is preserved. But way down 20 thousand lines later I see the new version number there. I'll leave this around in case someone else has the same curiosity.